# HTML how can i separate arabic lam alef لا to two spans?

Tags: html

Yesterday i spent several hours for how to display lam alef in arabic in 2 separate spans with 2 different colors but with no success it show that ل‎‍ ‍‎ا

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
<style>
#lam {
  color: green;
}

  #alef {
  color: blue;
}
</style>

<p><span id="lam">&#1604;&#8206;&#8205; &#8205;</span> <span id="alef">alef</span></p>
```

See [this code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/sw3w3bcs/4/)

Use this to convert your characters into HTML special characters. https://www.charset.org/html-special-characters

Comment: Oh ,I mean in arabic like لا

Comment: @aym1781969 see edited above, just convert the Arabic characters into HTML special characters. Like it if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get two different colors displayed in two different span elements by using this syntax:

```
<p><span style="color:green;">GREEN TEXT</span> <span style="color:blue;">BLUE TEXT</span></p>
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/sw3w3bcs/1/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Oh ,I mean in arabic like لا

Comment: You should be able to type whatever you'd like in between the two span tags. So where it says "GREEN TEXT", simply type whatever you want to be green in there, and same for any other color